# должны работать как китайцы - СИС?

Tags: сказуемые

Нужна ли запятая в предложении:
Мы должны работать, как китайцы.
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Запятая не ставится, если слова "работать как китайцы" представляют собой предикат (сказуемое).

По-моему, здесь составное именное сказуемое - должны работать как китайцы.

Answer (score 3):

Мы должны работать как китайцы.

Однозначно нет запятой, оборот является  обстоятельством в основном сообщении. Что хотел сказать автор? Наверное, что мы должны работать много,усердно, именно это значение передает оборот "как китайцы".

Для сравнения: Мы, как китайцы, должны работать. Но работают все люди, не только китайцы. Обособленный оборот не имеет смысла.

Но: Мы должны работать усердно, как китайцы (обособление оборота в качестве второго обстоятельства).

Answer (score 2):

Все правильно. Запятая ставится или не ставится в зависимости от того входит ли оборот ***с как*** в сказуемое.

Некоторые предложения допускают двоякую пунктуацию в зависимости от их истолкования;

> ср.:Он работал как батрак — ***‘в качестве батрака’, ‘батраком’.***
>   Он работал, как батрак — ***‘много’, ‘подобно батраку’.***

***Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь. Д. Э.***

В вашем случае, запятая, наверно, все же нужна. Мы должны работать, как китайцы( много, подобно китайцам). ***Нельзя же сказать: в качестве китайцев.***

Comment: _Серж: "Нельзя же сказать: в качестве китайцев"._ === Но можно сказать: **по-китайски.** См.: § 90. Обороты со сравнительными союзами (частицами) _как, словно, будто, точно, как будто, что_ не выделяются запятыми в следующих случаях... 
г) если оборот имеет значение образа действия (такие обороты можно заменить творительным падежом существительного **или наречием**)... (http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125 )

Comment: Да, верно, не подумал. Но и здесь запятая вариативна.

Comment: _Но и здесь запятая вариативна._ === Согласен.

Answer (score 1):

Считаю, что запятая обязательна: чистейший сравнительный оборот.

**Розенталь:**
*2. Запятыми выделяются или отделяются сравнительные обороты, начинающиеся союзом как:
1) если они обозначают уподобление, без других оттенков значения (как имеет значение «подобно»...* [и далее куча примеров, подобных данному]*)*

Неужели могут быть какие-то вопросы?!